# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (13500,) and (13476,) Despite working with other Dataset?

Tags: python, excel, matplotlib, xlrd

I was trying to plot an excel dataset, however, one dataset is able to plot and with the second one I get an error message.

My code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from xlrd import open_workbook

x_time = list()
y_absorbance = list()

book = open_workbook("SP1.xls")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)                  #data is on sheet 1

column1 = sheet.col_values(0)
column2 = sheet.col_values(1)

for x in column1:
    try:
        num = float(x)
        time = num/1000000
        x_time.append(time)
    except:
        continue

for y in column2:
    try:
        num = float(y)
        absorbance = num/1000000
        y_absorbance.append(absorbance)
    except:
        continue

plt.plot(x_time, y_absorbance)

plt.title("Final Analysis native R5 Main Pool", fontname="Times New Roman",fontweight="bold", size=20)
plt.xlabel("run time [min]", fontname="Times New Roman")
plt.ylabel("Absorbance [mAU]", fontname="Times New Roman")
plt.legend(("UV-VIS 214 nm",), loc="upper right")

plt.show()
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nico/PycharmProjects/Exercise/HPLC_plot.py", line 29, in <module>
plt.plot(x_time, y_absorbance)
  File "/Users/nico/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2840, in plot
return gca().plot(
  File "/Users/nico/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1743, in plot
lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
  File "/Users/nico/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 273, in __call__
yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
  File "/Users/nico/PycharmProjects/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 399, in _plot_args
raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (13500,) and (13476,)
```

The data is an excel sheet and looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/npJDy.png

[The other plot looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgUlD.png)

so this is how the plot should look like.

I do not know what I am doing wrong since with the first dataset it works and the second data set is from the same HPLC-software just from another run.

Any suggestions are appreciated in advance! :)

Comment: Using the module matplotlib & xlrd

Comment: You should combine both try-except loops into one.

Comment: Thanks sooo much!! works with itertools and combining those two for loops into one which yields only one try-except block !!

Comment: Just `for x, y in zip(column1, column2):`